# Scrapy no crawl on first page with rule to follow next page

Tags: python, scrapy, rule, web-crawler

I made a spider with recursive rule to follow the link of next page. it works fine.
The spider crawl all pages (999) except the first page defined in "start_urls".
Has someone ever had the problem ?

a example code :

```
class example(CrawlSpider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["example.ndd"]
    start_urls = ["http://example.ndd/startnum=1"] #first page  

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("nextPage\.htm", ),
                            restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="paging"]/p[@class="nav"]',)), 
                            callback="parse_items", follow= True),)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        links= hxs.select('//td[@class="desc"]/h3/a/@href').extract()
        list = []
        for link in links:
            yield link
        return
```

edit: after searching, the crawler seeams follow directly the result of restrict path of the rule. So same if begin by startnum=1, it crawl startnum=11 which is inside the page of startnum=1 ..
I don't know how solve this problem.

Comment: You're probably going to have to post the genuine snippet and urls

Answer (score 6):

You need to use: `def parse_start_url(self, response):`

See this answer: [Scrapy CrawlSpider doesn't crawl the first landing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836062/scrapy-crawlspider-doesnt-crawl-the-first-landing-page)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to crawl the `start_urls` and extract it as well as the other pages?

`CrawlSpider` will not extract items from `start_urls`. If you want to, overload the **parse** method.