# scrapy Scraped contents on landing page is not passed through pipelines

Tags: scrapy

I have a elasticsearch pipeline which will index all the scraped content into elasticsearch. My problem is the contents scraped from the start_urls page are indexed. Those data are not even passed through my elasticsearch pipeline. What am I missing? Is there any settings in scrapy to achieve it? Does scrapy considers scraped contents only from page crawled from the start_url page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836062/scrapy-crawlspider-doesnt-crawl-the-first-landing-page

Comment: But the scraped content isn't passing through the pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me, although make sure that you have added your pipeline in settings.py

```
    ITEM_PIPELINES = { "your_pipeline": 100 }
```

Comment: Thanks guys... I found the problem. I was missing return in parse_start_url method.