# Using Regex to Select Index Page Only

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

Is there regex to select on the index page when crawling a specific website? I'm select certain pages but also need just the index page on top of those.

I can't seem to figure out the proper way to put it. Basically, I want to crawl index page, contact page, about page, and advertise page to look for contact information.

Here is the code.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
import csv
from urlparse import urlparse

class MailItem(Item):
    desc = Field()
    title = Field()
    url = Field()
    mail = Field()

class MailSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "marksey"

    parsed_hostnames= set()

rules = [
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/contact',r'/about',r'/advertise',)), callback='parse_item', follow=True)
]

###r'^https?://[^/]+(/(\?.*|index\.php(\?.*)?)?)?$',

start_urls = []
allowed_domains = []
with open('C:\Users\Vasily\MyStuff\emailtest\emailtest\scraped_data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        url = row[0].strip()
        if (url.strip() != ""):
            start_urls.append(url)
            hostname = urlparse(url).hostname
            allowed_domains.append(hostname)

def parse_item(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    items = []

for sel in response.xpath('//html/head'):
    item = MailItem()
    item['title'] = sel.xpath('title/text()').extract()
    item['desc'] = sel.xpath('//meta[@name=\'description\']/@content').extract()
    item['url'] = response.url
    item['mail'] = hxs.select('//body//text()').re(r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+')

    if not item['mail']:
        item['mail'] = item['url']

    items.append(item)
    hostname = urlparse(response.url).hostname
    self.parsed_hostnames.add(hostname)

return items

def process_links(self, links):
    return [l for l in links if urlparse(l.url).hostname not in self.parsed_hostnames]
```

Comment: If you only want to parse 4 pages, there is no point in using a `CrawlSpider`. Just use a regular `Spider`, and put the links you want to parse in `start_urls`

Comment: So if I'm crawling 1000 domains I should put 4000 urls there?

Comment: No, if you're actually crawling, use a `CrawlSpider` (you can still give it some start urls), but you wrote "I want to crawl index page, contact page, about page, and advertise page to look for contact information".

Comment: @stranac I think the OP means `start_urls` is having 4000 urls for multiple domains and he is inspecting them for the contact information checking about, contact, advertise and index endpoints.

Comment: @alecxe Ah, I see. I guess I misread his comment (and the original question, it would seem)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear - but yes, @alecxe is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to call `parse_item()` callback from the `parse_start_url()` - this way you would also parse the url coming from `start_urls`, which is I am assuming is an index page:

```
class MailSpider(CrawlSpider):
    ...

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        return self.parse_item(response)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = []
        ...
```

See also:

- [Scrapy CrawlSpider doesn't crawl the first landing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836062/scrapy-crawlspider-doesnt-crawl-the-first-landing-page)