# Item not included in for loop made in Scrapy

Tags: python, mysql, xpath, scrapy

I think there is likely to be a simple solution to this problem... All i am trying to do is extract text listing a genre type with my variable item ['genre'], simple enough... However, as the item i am extracting only appears on the page i am scraping from once, when looping through the other items such as item ['artist'], the item ['genre'] is not included. Any help would be appreciated. Here is what i believe to be the relevant code.

```
def parse_item(self, response):#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836062/scrapy-crawlspider-doesnt-crawl-the-first-landing-page
    for info in response.xpath('//div[@class="entry vevent"] | //div[@id="page"]'):
        item = TutorialItem() # Extract items from the items folder.
        item ['artist'] = info.xpath('.//span[@class="summary"]//text()').extract() # Extract artist information.
        item ['date'] = info.xpath('.//span[@class="dates"]//text()').extract() # Extract date information.
        preview = ''.join(str(s)for s in item['artist'])
        item ['genre'] = info.xpath('.//div[@class="header"]//text()').extract()
```

Really hope this makes sense, apologies if not!

Comment: Post the relevant HTML or link to the page you're trying to scrape..

Comment: http://www.allgigs.co.uk/whats_on/London/clubbing-1.html 

You'll see that the words clubbing overview are what im trying to extract. Does it once per page instead of alongside the other items

Comment: I guess you're not asking about the XPath to get that words, no? Then what's the problem to extract that words again?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand... My problem is that as the results are returned i get the artist name, the date of an event. However the item genre returns empty. It only displays once as the crawler visits the next page. This is no good as i need to add the information to a database

Comment: Perhaps you should simply put the `item ['genre'] = info.xpath('.//div[@class="header"]//text()').extract()` statement outside of the loop

Comment: no good, as then when added to the database the text is not associatted with all the results under the item name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason why you are getting the **genre** only once is, the return list of `response.xpath('//div[@class="entry vevent"] | //div[@id="page"]')` will contain one **div(with id="page")** and a bunch of **div (with class="entry vevent")**

while iterating through the above list the `div[@id="page"]` will satisfy the **genre** xpath,

ie, this **div** contains another **div** which has an **class="header"**

```
In [1]: a = response.xpath('//div[@class="entry vevent"] | //div[@id="page"]')

In [2]: a[0].xpath('.//div[@class="header"]//text()').extract()
Out[2]: [u'Clubbing Overview']

In [3]: a[1].xpath('.//div[@class="header"]//text()').extract()
Out[3]: []

In [4]: a[2].xpath('.//div[@class="header"]//text()').extract()
Out[4]: []
...
```

and on the other side **div[@class="entry vevent"]**, it doesn't contains any **div** which has an **class="header"** so ultimately will lead to get the empty list as output

make sense ?

one solution is to put that **genre** xpath outside the loop or you can modify the xpath of genre as

```
info.xpath('.//div[@class="header"]//text() | ./parent::div[@class="rows"]/preceding-sibling::div[@class="header"]//text()').extract()
```

Comment: Great answer. I'll research into this some more. Thank-you so much!! I'm guessing the preceding-sibling comes back out of the link it just scraped?

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss `return item` at the end of the loop

Comment: I use yield at the end of the loop