# Checking one array against another in python and scrapy

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, scrapy

I am trying to set a variable in Python to an string element in one array based on the string element being used in another. I'm quite stumped how to do it though.

Here are the two arrays:

```
genre = ["Dance",
    "Festivals",
    "Rock/pop"
    ]
```

I am trying to print genre based on these three elements in another array ie when start_urls = [0], genre = [0]:

```
start_urls = [
    "http://www.allgigs.co.uk/whats_on/London/clubbing-1.html",
    "http://www.allgigs.co.uk/whats_on/London/festivals-1.html",
    "http://www.allgigs.co.uk/whats_on/London/tours-1.html"
]
```

Full code:

```
genre = ["Dance",
    "Festivals",
    "Rock/pop"
    ]

class AllGigsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "allGigs" # Name of the Spider. In command promt, when in the correct folder, enter "scrapy crawl Allgigs".
    allowed_domains = ["www.allgigs.co.uk"] # Allowed domains is a String NOT a URL. 
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.allgigs.co.uk/whats_on/London/clubbing-1.html",
        "http://www.allgigs.co.uk/whats_on/London/festivals-1.html",
        "http://www.allgigs.co.uk/whats_on/London/tours-1.html"
    ] 

    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="more"]'), # Search the start URL's for 
        callback="parse_item", 
        follow=True),
    ]

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        return self.parse_item(response)

    def parse_item(self, response):#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836062/scrapy-crawlspider-doesnt-crawl-the-first-landing-page
        for info in response.xpath('//div[@class="entry vevent"]'):
            item = TutorialItem() # Extract items from the items folder.
            item ['artist'] = info.xpath('.//span[@class="summary"]//text()').extract() # Extract artist information.
            item ['date'] = info.xpath('.//span[@class="dates"]//text()').extract() # Extract date information.
            preview = ''.join(str(s)for s in item['artist'])
            #item ['genre'] = i.xpath('.//li[@class="style"]//text()').extract()
            client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='401c04a7271e93baee8633483510e263', client_secret='b6a4c7ba613b157fe10e20735f5b58cc', callback='http://localhost:9000/#/callback.html')
            tracks = client.get('/tracks', q = preview, limit=1)
            for track in tracks:
                print track.id
                for i, val in enumerate(genre):
                        print '{} {}'.format(genre[i], start_urls[i]) 
                print genre
                #for i, val in enumerate(genre):
                #       print '{} {}'.format(genre[i], start_urls[i])
                item ['trackz'] = track.id
                yield item
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You could use `dicts` if you want to map two arrays?

Comment: Put your expected output\

Comment: My expected output would just be to set an item ['genre'] to whatever corresponds with the link being scraped. So the first url would just send a string "dance" to my database

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, val in enumerate(genre):
    print '{} {}'.format(genre[i], start_urls[i])
```

should work

Comment: i get an error about the global variable 'start_urls' not existing. I'll edit the question with the full code.... and thankyou :)

Comment: Your start_urls is an attribute of a class, so you have to use self, like this self.start_urls[i]

Comment: Thats awesome and is working better. However this prints out all three genres and the three urls. I just want to print the genre that matches the url being scraped if that makes sense??

Comment: then you have to get index of genre you want to print and print genre[i]. I don't know how to get index of genre you want, you have to know that.

Comment: I dont understand the comment. Sorry, I'm a newbie to python. If the first url is being scraped, then the index of genre would need to be [0]. If the second url is being scraped the index of genre would need to be [1] right? Its just finding how to do this

Comment: ah, that way, then you have to somehow pass index of url to parse_item method: parse_item(self, response, url_index):

Comment: not possible to do something like this?? if self.start_urls==[0]:
                                  print genre[0]