# Duplicate results error when trying to scrape a 'show more results' href in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping, duplicates

I am trying to scrape a web page that has a display more results option. set the restrict xpaths like so...

```
(restrict_xpaths='//a[@href="#"]')
```

However, because the results are displayed on the same page, scrapy wishes to scrape all results again and receives "duplicate results" and crashes when the crawler is ran. I believe after reading it may be something to do with a dont_filter option?

Here is a link to the website...

```
http://www.skiddle.com/whats-on/London/?sort=18&from_date=15+Apr+2015&to_date=&radius=10&rkeep=&eventcodes%5B%5D=6&view=gallery
```

Thanks guys

my spider

```
import scrapy # Import required libraries.
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector # Allows for path detection in a websites code.
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider # Used to create a simple spider to extract data.
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor # Needed for the extraction of href links in HTML to crawl further pages.
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider # Needed to make the crawl spider.
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule # Allows specified rules to affect what the link 
from urlparse import urlparse
import soundcloud
import mysql.connector
import requests
import time
from datetime import datetime
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

from tutorial.items import TutorialItem

class Skiddle_ClubSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Skiddle_Club" # Name of the Spider. In command promt, when in the correct folder, enter "scrapy crawl Allgigs".
    allowed_domains = ["www.skiddle.com"] # Allowed domains is a String NOT a URL. 
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.skiddle.com/whats-on/London/?sort=18&from_date=15+Apr+2015&to_date=&radius=10&rkeep=&eventcodes%5B%5D=6&eventcodes%5B%5D=4&view=gallery"
    ] 

    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[@href="#"]'), # Search the start URL's for 
        callback="parse_item1", 
        follow=True),
    ]

    def parse_start_url(self, response):#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836062/scrapy-crawlspider-doesnt-crawl-the-first-landing-page
        return self.parse_item1(response)

    def parse_item1(self, response):
        items = []
        for info in response.xpath('//div[@class="moveable"]'):
            item = TutorialItem() # Extract items from the items folder.
            item ['table'] = "London"
            item ['artist'] = info.xpath('.//div[@class="summary"]//text()').extract()[1] # Extract artist information.

            items.append(item)

        return items
```

Answer (score 1):

I think intead of crawl spider BaseSpider will do the job, 
check the code below

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider # Used to create a simple spider to extract data.
from datetime import datetime
from scrapy.http import  Request
from skiddle.items import *
import re

class Skiddle_ClubSpider(Spider):
    name = "Skiddle_Club"
    allowed_domains = ["www.skiddle.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.skiddle.com/whats-on/London/?sort=18&from_date=15+Apr+2015&to_date=&radius=10&rkeep=&eventcodes%5B%5D=6&eventcodes%5B%5D=4&view=gallery"
    ] 

    def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
        self.today = datetime.today().strftime('%d+%b+%Y')
        self.start_urls = ["http://www.skiddle.com/whats-on/London/?sort=18&from_date={}&to_date=&radius=10&rkeep=&eventcodes%5B%5D=6&eventcodes%5B%5D=4&view=gallery".format(self.today)]

    def parse(self, response):
        _next_page_url = 'http://www.skiddle.com/whats-on/London/?ajaxing=1&sort=18&from_date={}&to_date=&radius=10&rkeep=&eventcodes%5B%5D=6&view=gallery&o=0&bannertitle={}'.format(self.today,self.today)
        yield Request(url=response.url, meta={'next': _next_page_url} , callback=self.parse_artist)

    def parse_artist(self, response):
        artists = response.xpath('//div[@class="summary"]/a/text()').extract()
        if artists:
            for artist in artists:
                item = TutorialItem( # Extract items from the items folder.
                table="London",
                artist=artist.replace('\\t', '').replace('\\r', '').replace('\\n', '')
                )
                yield item
        else:
            return

        page_index = re.findall('&o=(\d+)&bannertitle',response.meta['next'])
        if page_index:
            next_page_url = 'http://www.skiddle.com/whats-on/London/?ajaxing=1&sort=18&from_date={}&to_date=&radius=10&rkeep=&eventcodes%5B%5D=6&view=gallery&o={}&bannertitle={}'.format(self.today,str(int(page_index[0])+ 24) ,self.today) 
            yield Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse_artist, meta={'next': next_page_url})
```

pagination is done using ajax request, you can see the ajax url in the **next_page_url** and updated the start-url according to the date of crawl too.

Comment: good but for me it only scrapes the first part of the page. It doesnt call the ajax sorting