# Scrapy Crawler does not working when there is no link pagination on root page

Tags: python, scrapy

My scrapy crawler don't work as expected all the times.

I scrap some categorie from a webshop which contains pagination inside each categorie page but sometimes it does not contain the link pagination because there is only one page

My rule works only if link pagination are inside the page i selected  but i don't know how to make it works when the root page of the category is the only one.

here is my rule.

```
rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(),restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="button button_gris button_medium"]',)), callback='parse_item', follow=True)
```

Any idea how to make it to scrape also the page not containing pagination link which i target.

Note:

I launch the crawl spider using a start url populated by mysqlDB like this for example where the arg table used to select my link table where start url is used.

```
scrapy crawl mg_bot_crawler -a table=mini_four
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your callback to parse_start_url and override it, see this answer [Scrapy CrawlSpider doesn't crawl the first landing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836062/scrapy-crawlspider-doesnt-crawl-the-first-landing-page)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. It was perfect. I found another solution but your aproach looks like the good way. Just for info on my solution. There was a breadcumb link inside my landing page so a I just write a new rule like this: `Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(),restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="product_breadcrumb"]/a[last()]')), callback='parse_item', follow=False)`