# scrapy does not scrape parent URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I have an html file `demo1.html` with code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

“What is this obsession people have with books? They put them in their houses—like they’re trophies.
What do you need it for after you read it?” – Jerry

<a href="file:///path/to/demo2.html"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see, In `demo1.html` file I have added link to another html file named `demo2.html` (`<a href="file:///path/to/demo2.html"></a>`)

**demo2.html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

“Tuesday has no feel. Monday has a feel, Friday has a feel, Sunday has a feel…” – Newman

</body>
</html>
```

I have written a spider which would **scrape** the plaintext from the html files and store it in text file namely *basename.txt*, with respect to each url.

**My spider code:**

```
from os.path import splitext
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from os.path import basename
import lxml

FOLLOW = True

class CustomLinkExtractor(LinkExtractor):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLinkExtractor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.deny_extensions = [".zip", ".mp4", ".mp3"]  # ignore files with mentioned extensions

def get_plain_html(response_body):
    root = lxml.html.fromstring(response_body)
    lxml.etree.strip_elements(root, lxml.etree.Comment, "script", "head", "style")
    text = lxml.html.tostring(root, method="text", encoding='utf-8')
    return text

def get_file_name(url):
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    file_name = basename(parsed_url.path.strip('/')) if parsed_url.path.strip('/') else parsed_url.netloc
    return file_name



class WebScraper(CrawlSpider):
    name = "goblin"
    start_urls = [
        'file:///path/to/demo1.html'
    ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.rules = (Rule(CustomLinkExtractor(), follow=FOLLOW, callback="parse_file"),)
        super(WebScraper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse_file(self, response):
        try:
            file_name = get_file_name(response.url)
            if hasattr(response, "text"):
                file_name = '{0}.txt'.format(file_name)
                text = get_plain_html(response.body)
                file_path = './{0}'.format(file_name)
                with open(file_path, 'wb') as f_data:
                    f_data.write(text)
        except Exception as ex:
            self.logger.error(ex, exc_info=True)
```

When I run my spider I can see `demo2.html` being scraped and the text:

> “Tuesday has no feel. Monday has a feel, Friday has a feel, Sunday has a feel…” – Newman

is stored in `demo2.html.txt`, but my spider does not return any response for`demo1.html` which is a part of the url in `start_urls` list.

I am expecting a file `demo1.html.txt` to be created with text:

> “What is this obsession people have with books? They put them in their houses—like they’re trophies.
> What do you need it for after you read it?” – Jerry

Note: I have set `DEPTH_LIMIT = 1` in `settings.py`

**Scrapy Logs:**

```
2020-06-17 20:33:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.1.0 started (bot: scrapy_project)
2020-06-17 20:33:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:50:52) - [GCC 8.3.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 2.9.2, Platform Linux-...-Ubuntu-...
2020-06-17 20:33:27 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2020-06-17 20:33:27 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED': True,
 'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True,
 'BOT_NAME': 'scrapy_project',
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 30,
 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
 'DEPTH_LIMIT': 1,
 'DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE': 5242880,
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrapy_project.spiders',
 'REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE': 20,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrapy_project.spiders']}
2020-06-17 20:33:27 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: *******
2020-06-17 20:33:27 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.throttle.AutoThrottle']
2020-06-17 20:33:27 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy_project.middlewares.FilterResponses',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.ajaxcrawl.AjaxCrawlMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-06-17 20:33:27 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-06-17 20:33:27 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-06-17 20:33:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-06-17 20:33:27 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-06-17 20:33:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET file:///path/to/demo1.html> (referer: None)
2020-06-17 20:33:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET file:///path/to/demo2.html> (referer: None)
2020-06-17 20:33:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-06-17 20:33:33 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 556,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 646,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 6.091841,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 17, 15, 3, 33, 427522),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 14,
 'memusage/max': 1757986816,
 'memusage/startup': 1757986816,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 17, 15, 3, 27, 335681)}
2020-06-17 20:33:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
Process finished with exit code 0
```

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The logs show that demo1 is crawled, but you say it is not. They also show no item being scraped from any of the two URLs. Which seems to contradict your question.

Comment: Hi Gallaecio, all I am doing is reading the response.body in 'parse_file' method. When I debug my code I can see the  method 'parse_file' gets invoked for demo2.html, but not for demo1.html.

Comment: Is that log from your debugging session, or from a separate run?

Comment: Hi @Gallaecio, the logs are from separate run and  it looks like I need to override "parse_start_url" (reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836062/scrapy-crawlspider-doesnt-crawl-the-first-landing-page). I am still testing hence can't be sure.

Comment: I had to override ```parse_start_url``` Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839428/10011503

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my callback to `parse_start_url` and override it.

Refer answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839428/10011503

Complete code with expected changes:

```
from os.path import splitext
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from os.path import basename
import lxml

FOLLOW = True

class CustomLinkExtractor(LinkExtractor):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLinkExtractor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.deny_extensions = [".zip", ".mp4", ".mp3"]  # ignore files with mentioned extensions

def get_plain_html(response_body):
    root = lxml.html.fromstring(response_body)
    lxml.etree.strip_elements(root, lxml.etree.Comment, "script", "head", "style")
    text = lxml.html.tostring(root, method="text", encoding='utf-8')
    return text

def get_file_name(url):
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    file_name = basename(parsed_url.path.strip('/')) if parsed_url.path.strip('/') else parsed_url.netloc
    return file_name



class WebScraper(CrawlSpider):
    name = "goblin"
    start_urls = [
        'file:///path/to/demo1.html'
    ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.rules = (Rule(CustomLinkExtractor(), follow=FOLLOW, callback="parse_file"),)
        super(WebScraper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        return self.parse_file(response)

    def parse_file(self, response):
        try:
            file_name = get_file_name(response.url)
            if hasattr(response, "text"):
                file_name = '{0}.txt'.format(file_name)
                text = get_plain_html(response.body)
                file_path = './{0}'.format(file_name)
                with open(file_path, 'wb') as f_data:
                    f_data.write(text)
        except Exception as ex:
            self.logger.error(ex, exc_info=True)
```